# Spring Web MVC Not Started In WebLogic Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, weblogic, weblogic12c

Hi I have a spring web mvc and I use spring 2.x  I have @restcontroller annotation to run my rest services.I already  added weblogic.xml,dispatcherservlet.xml,and create war file and exclude tomcat in my war.

I installed war to weblogic and when I try to start it,status hangs on start initializing.I cant see any errors in logs.

MyWeblogic version is 14.1.1

Can some one know the issue and solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I created virtual host and some missing configuration about listener.When I change my config and try it to default admin server war file is working.So my problem root cause is about missing configuration in weblogic.